# Order of component life cycle with react-redux connect and redux data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

We all know that `constructor -> componentWillMount -> componentDidMount` is order of execution.

Now when redux comes into play and trying to access redux properties in our component life cycle. What is the order in which **connect will execute** so that **data is available lifecycle methods** ignoring and data updation to redux. The possibilities are

```
1. Connect (DATA AVAILABLE) -> constructor & componentWillMount & componentDidMount

2. constructor -> Connect (DATA AVAILABLE) -> componentWillMount & componentDidMount

3. constructor -> componentWillMount -> Connect (DATA AVAILABLE) -> componentDidMount

4. constructor -> componentWillMount -> componentDidMount -> Connect (DATA AVAILABLE)
```

and is the **order consistent** or **depends** on the data that is loaded?

and is it different between **react and react native**

and is it okay to defined redux properties as **required in PropType**

Comment: can you provide your use case for better understanding of problem

Comment: I hope its a general scenario and doesn't have any specific use case @abby37

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`connect` is an HOC which wraps your component, so the component lifecycle method comes after the connect lifecycle. For simple understanding, you can think of connect being written like this

```
const connect = (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) => (Component) => {
    return class ReduxApp extends React.Component {
        // lifecycle of connect
        render() {
            return (
                 <Component {...mapStateToProps(state)} />
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Now whenever your state updates, connect will shallow compare the list of props to be returned to Component and if there is a change update the props, after which the component lifecycle method runs like a prop is being updated.

In short the execution initially is

```
Connect (DATA AVAILABLE) -> constructor & componentWillMount & componentDidMount
```

Once the data is updated

```
Connect (DATA AVAILABLE) -> componentWillReceiveProps/getDerivedStateFromProps -> componentWillUpdate -> render -> componentDidUpdate
```

Comment: so replying on your answer which answers all my question.
1. Connect (DATA AVAILABLE) -> constructor & componentWillMount & componentDidMount is the order
2. order of execution is consistent
3.  and is same for react and react-native
4.  and yes it is okay to define required in PropType for redux properties

Answer (score 4):

The initial execution order would be -

Connect (DATA AVAILABLE) -> constructor & componentWillMount & Render & componentDidMount

When the site is fired up, redux connect would be initialized first with its default states and actions before the component mount life cycles. However, if there are API calls in redux, the component mount life cycles will not wait for the data. Instead component update life cycles will be invoked, if the component is already mounted and redux returns a data.